# How to create ternary relationship in sql

Tags: sql, database, relation

I'm trying to create a hospital RDBMS and i need to create a ternary relationship between doctor, department, and patient, the ER part of the ER diagram which they need be assigned in that way. But I couldn't create their tables in the database.

[image]

The relationships are :

Many doctor can assign many patients and patients can assign many doctor, but many of the two(doctor and patient) can assign one department.

How can I create their SQL tables ?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, a better explanation of what you want, and a database tag.

Answer (score 0):

### Tables

```
Department
Doctor (with FK of Department)
Patient (with FK of Department)
DoctorPatient (With FKs of Doctor & Patient)
```